# How to change a column value to sub_string value of another column autoatically

Tags: mysql, triggers, substring

I have two columns in my mysql table, `equipment` and `orderno`, Here equipment number is manually inserted, and they are in the form `C1234`,`C3212` etc.

I want to strip the `C` from `equipment` column and insert the remaining number to `orderno` column. I have seen that mysql `substring_index()` can effectively get substring but I am not sure how to make it automtically do the changes, when the `equipment` column changes.

Comment: So, what do you have so far?

Comment: create trigger which execute on change of equipment column update/add.
check below link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547465/updating-table-in-trigger-after-update-on-the-same-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two triggers, one that's fired before an INSERT, and one that's fired before an UPDATE, to automatically update `orderno` based on `equipment` column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_your_table BEFORE UPDATE ON your_table 
FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.orderno=substring(new.equipment, 2)
;
CREATE TRIGGER ins_your_table BEFORE INSERT ON your_table 
FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.orderno=substring(new.equipment, 2)
;
```

To update existing values, you could use this:

```
UPDATE your_table SET orderno=substring(equipment, 2)
```

[See this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c320f/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
UPDATE myTable set orderno= REPLACE(equipment, 'C', '')
```