# Error: Can't update table 'SampleTable' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql

I need to update media cell based on flag value after the insert trigger occurred.

My code is ...

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert AFTER INSERT ON SampleTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE SampleTable SET media = '../trigger/smile1.png' WHERE flag =0;
UPDATE SampleTable SET media = '../trigger/smile2.png' WHERE flag =1;
UPDATE SampleTable SET media = '../trigger/smile3.png' WHERE flag =2;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Trigger created successfully...

But when I try to insert values, it shows the following error.

"Can't update table 'SampleTable' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."

I don't understand what is the exact problem.

any help...

Comment: If you are trying to update one or more different rows in the same table as the trigger, that is not allowed in my sql

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: first you check with single query in that trigger. remove the other two query. while its working or not.

Comment: @PRABA no it's not work.

Comment: please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547465/updating-table-in-trigger-after-update-on-the-same-table

Comment: Thank u praba. I got an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_user_insert BEFORE INSERT ON SampleTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.flag =0 THEN
SET NEW.media = "../trigger/smile1.png";
ELSEIF NEW.flag = 1 THEN  
SET NEW.media = "../trigger/smile2.png";
ELSEIF NEW.flag = 2 THEN
SET NEW.media = "../trigger/smile3.png";
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```